# Blue star/dots icon at top left of ms project in apps bar

Tags: office365

I need help..
What is the meaning of the icon at the top left of app?

Appreciate your help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The icon means that this app is a new one for the current user. Once you assign a new license to a user, the corresponding app will appear with this icon, and meanwhile, the user will receive a notification in the top left banner of the portal.

I have tried to unlicensed and relicensed a product for a user in my test Office 365 account, and the icon shows as expected after re-licensed. I am working in Microsoft, and I did try to find some official articles about it. Unfortunately, sounds no such links now.

Comment: Hi Reken Liu, and welcome to Super User. This answer might very well be correct, but it would be significantly better as an answer if you can provide some sort of a citation for the claim made. A quote from a manual page with a link to the source would make a great addition to your answer; consider making an **[edit]** to that effect.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have tried to unlicensed and relicensed a product for a user in my test Office 365 account, and the icon shows as expected after re-licensed. I am working in Microsoft, and I did try to find some official articles about it. Unfortunately, sounds no such links now.